# how to open a page into a new window and print it

Tags: javascript

hi i try to do printing a page but it must open the page first in a new tab.
i have try to make the code. from my code i can open the page in a new tab but the print function do a print a blank page not the page that i direct open in a new tab.

how to fix that? please help me

this my code

```js
<script>
 function myFunction() {
    w=window.open("../../192.168.1.22/print_page/SPL_Karyawan.html");
 w.print();
 w.close();
 }
 
 </script>
```

Comment: your url isnt valid.

Comment: thats url is in my local data dude

Comment: Do you want to print it on the new tab or parent tab ?

Comment: @Tamilvanan in a new tab bro

Comment: @str when i try to delete the `w.print() and the w.close()` the page that i put in window.open can be loaded in newtab. but when i add `w.print() and the w.close` the page never open and just open the print dialog with black document

Comment: I think you have to add focus before print.

Comment: what i must targeted the focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is working for mine.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openNewWindow(){
var newWindow=window.open('redir2.html');
newWindow.focus();
newWindow.print();
newWindow.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open new window" onclick="openNewWindow()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Xc9/1/

Based on the comment, Given path in the window.redirect is wrong. It should be start with IP address with http.

Comment: still blank page has openned at the print dialog

Comment: maybe i have wrong type the path code?

Comment: ok done.. thx.. i just got wrong in my doc path